# Need to create a varchar column with length of 60000

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, sql-query-store

I am preparing a blog and for that i need my description with almost 50-60k characters .
for this i have create a column attribute called detail with 60000 length of type varchar(how ever the max length of varchar is 60k+).

but the attribute is directly changing as medium text (in PHPmy admin).
please help me to get me out of this.
the following one is the query generate by the engine.

```
ALTER TABLE `posts` CHANGE `detail` `detail` VARCHAR(60000) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL;
```

Thanks for the resolvers in advance:).

Answer (score 1):

For longer strings in MySQL, you can use one of the [text](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html) types.  In this case, `text` does what you want:

```
ALTER TABLE `posts` CHANGE `detail` `detail` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL;
```

Comment: my post consists of all the a lot of html tags will the text hold them exactly? even medium text is not doing that job i have already chceked

Comment: @maneeshsandra . . . It sounds like you are storing multiple values in a single column.  That sounds like a broken data model, but it is outside the scope of the question that you asked.  This answers the question that you asked.

Comment: no sir lot of html tags means a lot of <b> and <br> tags inside text that's what i am saying

Comment: mediumtext should hold HTML tags like `<b>` and `<br>` just fine, I suggest looking in to what's wrong going wrong with that, perhaps even opening another question about that since it's out of the scope of this question (you could link us to it, though).

Comment: By the way, you can make the change Gordon suggests graphically through phpMyAdmin by clicking the "Change" link for that column and modifying the type from the dropdown.